# Бесконечный цикл при получении списка юзеров через VK API

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, android-vksdk

Здравствуйте.

Использую официальное VK SDK и хочу получить список пользователей `VK` начиная с конкретного `id` и заканчивая каким-то числом. В документации ничего про множественные значения параметров не нашел и решил сделать тупо циклом `while`. Например, получить 20 пользователей.

```
do{
            VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_50", VKApiConst.USER_ID, String.valueOf(id)));

            request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                    super.onComplete(response);

                    VKList<VKApiUserFull> vkList = (VKList<VKApiUserFull>) response.parsedModel;

                    for (VKApiUserFull userFull : vkList) {
                        ... 
                        //фильтрация значений. Если проходят проверку, то счетчик увеличивается. Если нет, то - break
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            });
            id++;
        } while (count < 20);
```

Как уже было сказано выше, этот тупой цикл работает. Но есть проблема в том, что после своего выполнения он почему-то начинается заново. И продолжается до бесконечности. Сам цикл находится внутри метода `doInBackground` `AsyncTask`'а. При этом, после окончания цикла выполняется метод `onPostExecute`. А потом снова начинается цикл. Причем с того же самого момента, где он был остановлен. Т.е. с индексами 21, 22, 23 и т.д. Сидел с дебагером больше часа, но так и не смог понять, почему он уходит в бесконечный цикл. Вызывается `AsyncTask` по нажатию `Button`'a, поэтому зациклиться вызов там не мог.

Если описать все кратко, то все идет по такому сценарию:

1. Запускается `Activity`.
2. Запускается `AsyncTask` по нажатию клавиши.
3. Цикл проходит нужное число раз внутри `doInBackground` и прекращается.
4. Запускается `onPostExecute` в `AsyncTask`.
5. Проходит пару секунд и цикл снова запускается с того места, где он был остановлен.

Где мой промах?

**UPD**
То, что счетчик инкрементируется внутри самого запроса - не случайная ошибка. Он увеличивается только после того, как значения прошли фильтр. Именно в этом и состоит моя пробелма: мне нужно как-то остановить цикл не после 20 прохождений по нему, а после получения 20 объектов внутри `onComplete` запроса.

Избавиться от счетчика тоже не получается: while (arrayList.size() < 20) тоже приводит к бесконечному циклу.

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не там увеличиваете значение счётчика. Вы делаете это в методе `onComplete`, а он вызывается только после успешного выполнения запроса... Вообще не очень понятно что вы хотели этим кодом получить. И что за внутренний цикл ещё?..

У вас сейчас такой порядок действий в программе:

1. Заходим в `do`
2. Стартуем запрос
3. Инкреминируем `id`
4. Заходим в условие продолжения цикла и проверяем что `count` меньше 20
5. Возвращаемся к п.1 до тех пор пока не выполнится успешно 20 запросов.

Именно успешно выполнится, а не стартует, т.к. увеличиваете вы счётчик только после окончания запроса, а не после его старта. Да ещё и в цикле каком-то...

Вам надо как-то так:

```
do{
    VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_50", VKApiConst.USER_ID, String.valueOf(id)));

    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);

            VKList<VKApiUserFull> vkList = (VKList<VKApiUserFull>) response.parsedModel;

            for (VKApiUserFull userFull : vkList) {
                ...
               //count++;
            }
        }
    });
    count++;
    id++;
} while (count < 20);
```

---

Если же вам надо именно после выполнения задачи инкременировать счётчик, то и следующие задачи надо запускать только после выполнения предыдущей. Т.е. как-то так:

```
int id = 0;

public void foo(int count) {
    if (count>=20){return;}

    VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_50", VKApiConst.USER_ID, String.valueOf(id)));

    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);

            VKList<VKApiUserFull> vkList = (VKList<VKApiUserFull>) response.parsedModel;

            for (VKApiUserFull userFull : vkList) {
                ... 
                //фильтрация значений. Если проходят проверку, то счетчик увеличивается. Если нет, то - break
                count++;
            }
            foo(count);
        }
    });
    id++;
}
```

Comment: Это, конечно, верно, но мне нужно каким-то образом инкрементрировать счетчик внутри самого запроса, потому что там у меня находится (вместо ...) фильтрация получаемых значений. Т.е. мне нужно, не чтобы цикл прошел 20 раз, а чтобы было получено 20 объектов с нужными мне параметрами. Если запустить цикл в таком виде, в котором Вы предложили, то на выходе получится ArrayList из 1-2 объектов (остальные были отфильтрованы). А мне нужно получить именно 20 объектов. Если делать While до arrayList.size(), то тоже уходит в бесконечный цикл. В общем, данное решение мне не совсем подходит.

Comment: @ahgpoug, посмотрите обновление ответа - попробуйте запускать задачи рекурсивно, стартуя следующую только после выполнения текущей.

Comment: Посмотрел ответ. Как минимум, использование переменной count здесь невозможно, потому что в данном случае она должна быть final. Решил избавиться от нее, убрав ее из параметров метода и заменив проверку на if (arrayList.size() >= 20). Метод, вроде, выполняется, но делает это не нужное число раз. Т.е. в результате получается arrayList размера рандомного размера от 0 до 20. Не очень понимаю, почему это происходит, ведь рекурсия даже не доходит до того момента, когда ее нужно остановить.

Comment: UPD: вообще этот рекурсивный метод почему-то больше 7-8 не возвращает. Поставил условие на >=100, но возвращается он все равно 4-8.

Comment: @ahgpoug, может у вас не все запросы успешны, onComplete где-то не вызвался и больше ничто метод не вызвает. Вам бы надо добавить обработку ошибок

Comment: Спасибо, действительно некоторые запросы не выполняются, теперь работает. Но теперь есть небольшая проблема: раньше во время выполнения запросов на экране показывался ProgressDialog. Теперь он пропадает значительно раньше, чем данные будут загружены. Я так понимаю, что это связано с рекурсией. Возможно это как-нибудь учесть?

Comment: @ahgpoug, скорее всего вы где-то не там останавливаете диалог. Вам надо так: перед первичным вызовом метода  `foo` покажите диалог. В самом же методе в момент окончания всех процессов, т.е. после дохождения `count` до 20 - скройте диалог. Но тут также надо учесть возможные ошибки запросов.

Comment: В моем случае метод выполняется внутри doInBackground AsyncTask'a. ProgressDialog я выставляю onPreExecute и убираю onPostExecute. Самая же рекурсия происходит вообще в другом классе. Получается, onPostExecute выполняется раньше, чем завершается рекурсия. Создать ProgressDialog внутри самого метода я не могу, потому что он, опять же, выполняется в doInBackground, и я не могу из него обращаться в ui.

Comment: @ahgpoug, по хорошему вам надо отказаться от АсинкТаска как от устаревшего способа. И делать чрез модный RxJava. А так... Можно создать интерфейс, заимплементить его в активити, передать его в АсинкТаск и дёрнуть его метод отключения прогресса в нужный момент в onPostExecute, проверив, что всё уже сделано.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать решать это.